# How to create Enclave using Intel SGX SDK on LINUX

Tags: c++17, sgx, enclave

I am seeking assistance and guidance regarding Intel Software Guard Extensions (SGX) technology. I have successfully installed and built the Intel SGX SDK ,SGX Driver and Platform Software (PSW) on my LINUX system as per these instructions ( https://github.com/intel/linux-sgx )   and I've successfully compiled the codes under SampleCode folder, and now I'm interested in creating enclaves to secure data for my applications.

If anyone can provide me the proper documentation for the C++ codes and their explanation it'll be very helpful.
In SDK package there are two C++ file (App.cpp and Enclave.cpp) for every SampleCode.
and now I am trying to write a simple C++ program for addition of two number then where to write the logic and then how to create  an enclave for that logic.

I tried to write the function with addition logic in Enclave.cpp and calling it from App.cpp
It's throwing undefined refernce error.